# making a sticky cookie/session without NginxPlus

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm having a hard time making a connection sticky on my nginx.conf file. the current architecture is as follows

```
events {}

http {
    
    upstream flask-app {
        server flask-app:5000;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://flask-app;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

`flask-app` is a Python-based container that I scale up to 3 of them, the round-robin balancing works fine when I scale the containers up and my idea is that when I connect to a container I want this connection to be persistent for 5 minutes and then switch to another container and again after 5 minutes switch to another one
I want to do this with the help of an nginx container that runs the above conf file with this docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  flask-app:
      build:
        context: ./webapp
        dockerfile: dockerfile
      volumes:
        - ./logs/flask-app.log:/app/flask-app.log
      ports:
        - "5000"
      depends_on:
        - db
      restart: on-failure

  nginx:
      image: nginx
      volumes:
        - ./nginx.conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      depends_on:
        - flask-app
      ports:
        - "80:80"
  
  db:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=access_log
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "33012:3306"

volumes:
  data:
```

I scale the `flask-app` container when I up the compose `docker-compose up -d --build --scale flask-app=3`
all of the solutions I've seen require NginxPlus, and for NginxPlus free trial you require to have a business mail which I don't have.
I do have a cookie with a lifetime of 5 minutes in my flask code, this cookie containes the internal IP of the container which you connect to, I am somewhat convinced that using this cookie will be key
I'd love some help in this matter <3

what did I already try - I've already tried pulling custom DockerHub images and making my session persistent through Python but I specifically need nginx sticky cookie for this task

Comment: Have a look at [nginx sticky module](https://nginx-extras.getpagespeed.com/modules/sticky/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/services/#sticky-sessions ? It looks easier to me to use traefik.

Comment: first of all, thank you! but the task specifically asked me to use Nginx